# Is there no simple Wifi to ethernet rj45 adapter?

Tags: wifi, ethernet, network-adapter, adapter

### The situation

I want to connect a device to my home network.  The device only have a RJ45 port and doesn't have any usb port.  The device isn't far from my Wifi router, but I would prefer not to pass a wire through walls and ceiling. Instead, I was thinking to use a simple adapter that convert Wifi to an ethernet wire.

### The problem

But here the thing, it turns out that the only hardware I can find to fill in for this role are wifi extender,repeater and hotspot. Given the device to connect isn't far from the router, those hardwares would just broadcast Wifi waves on top of those broadcasted by my router and therefore, could end up actively help make my entire Wifi network worse by creating noise. I'm not willing to sacrifice on the quality of my Wifi just to plug a single dumb device. If it come down to it, I will punch hole in walls and ceiling before doing that.

### The question

Is there a device that simply connect to an WIFI network and convert the signal to an Ethernet port or cable?

Comment: You can usually turn off the "output" WiFi of WiFi repeaters and just use them to supply devices connected to their ethernet port. However, the interface and functionality differ greatly between models.
Another option would be an cellphone with a USB to Ethernet adapter and Ethernet tethering over USB enabled. Android 11 seems to support that by default.

This might be an X->Y problem. As long as you choose a sufficiently different band for your repeaters WiFi output, it will not interfere with your existing network.

Comment: What you are looking for is specifically called a "WiFi Bridge". It connects to an existing WiFi network and usually has one or more RJ-45 ports that are routed through the WiFi connection. A bridge is like a client on your network, it doesn't make its own new network but it does still contribute extra WiFi traffic on the same channel just like adding another laptop or a phone would. Also, most devices these days are all-in-one, so they do repeating/bridge/access point and can be configured to work in those different modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a wifi repeater, but I would use a [Netgear Powerline](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BYKITU2) to do this. It sends the ethernet connection over the existing power wires in your wall and you can get up to 1gpbs. If you use them, you can get lower latency as well as faster speeds than Wi-Fi. I have two of them and they work really well.

Comment: I ended up using this one, even though it is overkill for what I needed.

Comment: Great. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a raspberry Pi 4 computer which is about $50 + sd card + USB power supply.

1. install the standard Pi OS 64 bit
2. connect it to your wifi using raspi-config
3. plug an ethernet RJ45 cable from it into your device.
4. install and configure isc-dhcp-server or use static IP.
5. set ip sysctl ip_forwarding=1

I guess this might not be super simple, but it works and is relatively cheap.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as a "wireless ethernet bridge," but I don't know of any consumer models, only industrial models [like this one](https://www.icpdas-usa.com/wf_2572.html?r=colin) probably more than you're willing to spend, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Used Linksys WET610N are still available.